# lld-link error compiling chromium with ffmpeg additional calls

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, electron, llvm, chromium

After adding some calls to ffmpeg from the `ffmpeg_decoding_loop`, I have errors when compiling on Windows (both directly on Windows and when cross-compiling from linux).
What I don't understand is that it works without an issue on linux/macos.

I have multiple calls to ffmpeg code but let's boil it down to a representative example.

I call this :

```cpp
const AVFilter *buffer_src = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
```

On linux/macos : no problems.
On windows :

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: avfilter_get_by_name
>>> referenced by .\..\..\media\ffmpeg\ffmpeg_decoding_loop.cc:111
>>>               obj/media/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_decoding_loop.obj:(public: void __cdecl media::FFmpegDecodingLoop::InitFilterGraph(struct AVFrame *))
>>> referenced by .\..\..\media\ffmpeg\ffmpeg_decoding_loop.cc:112
>>>               obj/media/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_decoding_loop.obj:(public: void __cdecl media::FFmpegDecodingLoop::InitFilterGraph(struct AVFrame *))
```

Is there some additional configuration to be made on windows ?
I use visual studio 2019, windows 10.0.19041.0 sdk, llvm 10.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may stumble on this : if you use functions from third_party/ffmpeg in your chromium code make sure those functions are specified in `third_party/ffmpeg/chromium/ffmpeg.sigs`.
It is only used when compiling for windows (that's why my mac/linux builds where succeeding).